# Axios multiple then's

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

So I have a problem, I want so that this Axios returns me second then, and it doesn't work, and I can't understand why. So this second then returns me undefined, but I wanted to get ID from that or any data, any suggestions? I checked some other posts, they seemed to have the same writing, but for me it just doesn't work, help pls:)

If you want to check Axios, at the end write ?q=Grimm (for example).
So the full page is: https://api.tvmaze.com/singlesearch/shows?q=Grimm

```
      .get('https://api.tvmaze.com/singlesearch/shows', {
        params: {
          q: id,
        },
      })
      .then((res) => setOneShow([res.data]))
      .then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Comment: The function in each then() controls what is returned. console.log() returns undefined so your last then() returns undefined. I don't know what setOneShow() returns but whatever it returns is what goes into the next then().

Comment: @Shan I think that's for `fetch` not axios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `.then() chain`, the second `then` block gets data returned from the first `then` block.

In your case, to get the same data in the second `then` block, alter your code as:

```
  axios.get("https://api.tvmaze.com/singlesearch/shows", {
        params: {
          q: id
        }
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("1", res);
        return res;
      })
      .then((res) => console.log("2", res));
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this lessons: [**Arrow Functions**](https://javascript.info/arrow-functions-basics), [**Promises**](https://javascript.info/promise-basics). You are calling and returning `setOneShow()` in your first `.then()` method, not `res`.
How it should looks like:

```js
axios.get('https://api.tvmaze.com/singlesearch/shows', {
   params: {
     q: id,
   },
 })
 .then((res) => {
   setOneShow([res.data]);
   return res;
 })
 .then((res) => {
   console.log(res);
 });
```

Comment: The first then doesn't return anything, so the second then will still log undefined.

Comment: I forgot to return `res`.